# facebook login IE not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I test the login button with jsfiddle on IE

I use

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: '113830492072210',
status: true,
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
oauth: true
});
 ....
```

the address is http://jsfiddle.net/Frizz1977/9rEuF/12/

All works fine, the app id is 113830492072210, I've find this sample on internet and i don't know how is configurated.

If I use my app id ( 729828323715843 ), the getLoginStatus method and the auth.login doesn't work

NOTE: chrome and firefox doesn't have this problem

Comment: You mean at chrome and firefox it works? If yes, can you please recheck - logout then login

Comment: With chrome and firefox i can login, listen the event, logout and all it works. With IE login doesn't work, I can't listen the event....

Comment: The exaple works, but if i get the code in my localhost application with my app id 729828323715843 I can't login

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your **SITE URL** properly in the App Settings.

If you are developing the application on localhost, say- `localhost/myapp`; then in the app settings you must give Site Url as `http://localhost/myapp` to get it work.